# Can't access admin page after Django CMS

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-admin, django-cms

**Versions:**  CentOS 6.4, Apache 2.2.15, Django 1.6, mod_wsgi 3.2

I am building a website and have the Django project files in the `/srv` directory.  I also have SELinux enabled.

I have the basic HTML and CSS already implemented for the website and am trying to use Django CMS to start building the meat of the site.  I followed their online documentation and managed to get the Django CMS welcome screen with that little white pony to appear.

However, when I visit: `<myIP>/admin`, I get a 404 Page Not Found error.  I believe I have the necessary admin code  in my files so I am looking for some help on this.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Used for CMS
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

# The next two lines enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^',               include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^$',             'mysite.views.home'),
    url(r'^admin/',         include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^support/$',      'mysite.views.support'),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

**Excerpts from settings.py**

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))[0]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': '/srv/mysite/database.sqlite',  
    } 
 }

 CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template1.html', 'Template 1'),
    ('template2.html', 'Template 2'),
 )

 INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admin',

     # These apps are for Django-CMS
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I can also provide any other snippets if it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to put `url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),` as the last entry of your url configuration, because `cms.urls` contains:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)$', details, name='pages-details-by-slug')
```

which also should match `/admin/`. So your `/admin/` request ends up in the cms, which doesn't have a page there, and 404s.